# Bottleneck In TPL I Think

Tags: .net, vb.net, task-parallel-library

I'm working on a small winforms app the moves\formats some files based on the content of the files.  I made a few hundred copies of the same file to see how long it took to process the files.  It processes 22000 kb's per second if i only iterate over 10 to 20 files but when i iterate over 150 to 200 files the kb's per second drops down to 11,000.  Of course more files will take longer but why would the kb's per second be dropping so much? The files are identical so what's going on? Here's a skeleton of the code....

```
       'classA
       For Each f As String In files
            Dim p As New Item(f)
            AddHandler p.InitCompleted, AddressOf DoWork

            Task.Factory.StartNew(Sub()
                                      p.StartInit()
                                  End Sub).Wait() 

        Next f

        'classA - - _scheduler declared at the class level and assigned FromCurrentSynchronizationContext
        Public Sub DoWork()
           'move/format files
            Task.Factory.StartNew(Sub() RaiseEvent AnEvent(intVal1, intVal2), Nothing, Threading.Tasks.TaskCreationOptions.None, _scheduler).Wait()

        End Sub

        'classItem 
          Private Sub Init() 
               'search file contents
                Task.Factory.StartNew(Sub()  RaiseEvent InitCompleted(), Nothing, Threading.Tasks.TaskCreationOptions.None, _scheduler).Wait()
          End Sub

          'gui winform
           AddHandler classa.AnEvent, AddressOf OnAnEvent

           Private Sub OnAnEvent(ByVal param1 Integer, ByVal param2 As Integer)
                txtBox1.Text = param1
                txtBox2.Text = Param2
           End Sub
```

Any input would be greatly appreciated. Answers in c# are fine.

Comment: Why are you starting tasks and immediately waiting for them? Seems to defeat the purpose.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Of course more files will take longer but why would the kb's per second be dropping so much?

Quite possibly *because* you're starting lots of files. You'll be IO-bound - a disk can only read or write one thing at a time. By giving it 200 files to read *at once*, you're making it much harder for it to actually do its work.

I suspect you may well find that if you just do *all* the IO in one thread, you'll actually find it's faster.

Additionally, you should use performance monitoring to see where the bottleneck is. I strongly expect it to be IO - but you should check. (Look at CPU usage, disk usage etc.)

Comment: Thanks for the input.  That helped but there's still something going on but I little more trial and error and hopefully I'll figure it out

Answer (score 0):

Resource Monitor included with Windows is something you can use to find bottlenecks in your application with 10-20 files, and then with 150-200 files being processed in parallel. As @JonSkeet mentioned, you are very likely to be IO-bound. Actually, even 10 parallel files is too much for a hard drive, but an SSD may show better performance here.

If you are working with big files, switching to sequential access may end up better overall. You should use TPL to parallel *CPU-bound* tasks.

Comment: Thanks for the input.  I'm trial and erroring it right now. The io issue was a problem.  A little more t & e and i think I'll have my logic error worked out